# Group files by date

Tags: java

I want to zip the files according to the month and year on which they are modified. I am able to get the month and year using simple date format.

```
package codes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class UsingLoops 
{
private static final String FOLDER_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Zip";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    File dir = new File(FOLDER_PATH);

    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName)
        {
            if (fileName.endsWith(".txt"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        });

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");

    for(File f:files)
    {
        System.out.println(f.getName());

        String month = sdf.format(f.lastModified());

        int j = Integer.parseInt(month);

        System.out.println(j);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to list the files according to the month and year.
For example

> 201412
> 201411 etc..

And how to give the name for the ZIP as the year and month automatically.

Help me out here....

I know how to zip using java, but I need it according to time and naming automation, hope you got my point

Comment: I know how to zip a file but I need a list according to time, and automated naming

Comment: You could use `Arrays.sort` and use a custom `Comparator` to sort the `File`s in what ever order you want.  You could use a `SimpleDateFormat` to format the value according to your requirements, you'd need to convert that to a `Date` first

Comment: Its not just to start, I need each list for every month

Comment: Define. What does 'a list according to time' mean? And 'automated naming'? And if your question isn't about about zipping files, why does that appear in your title? and your question?

Comment: *"Its not just to start, I need each list for every month"* - Sorry, what does that mean?

Comment: List according to time means I need a specific list of files for every month in a year

Comment: Still unclear. Why? And what is the point when you're zipping them? You need to make a proper effort here. You haven't yet asked an answerable question.

Comment: I want to zip the files according to the respective month, once I get the list I can zip them accordingly

Comment: You want to group all the files by their month and year?

Comment: So you want to sort the files by month? Do make a proper effort here, rather than just repeating yourself over and over again, when everybody is asking you to clarify.

Comment: Yes exactly Eg: 201412    201411 like wise

Comment: So you want to sort them by year and *then* by month?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SortedMap`, keyed by a `java.util.Date` to build a `List` of files which have been modified for a specific month/year, for example...

```
File[] files = ...;

Map<Date, List<File>> mapFiles = new TreeMap<>();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMM");
for (File file : files) {
    try {
        // This might seem weird, but basically, this will trim
        // off the date (day) and time, making it possible to
        // better match elements which fall within the same month
        // and year...
        // You could use a Calendar here to extract the Year and Month 
        // values, it would mean you're not creating so many short lived
        // objects, but that's up to you
        Date date = sdf.parse(sdf.format(new Date(file.lastModified())));
        List<File> group = mapFiles.get(date);
        if (group == null) {
            group = new ArrayList<>(25);
            mapFiles.put(date, group);
        }
        group.add(file);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Now, you can process the groups individually...
for (Date date : mapFiles.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    for (File file : mapFiles.get(date)) {
        System.out.println("    " + file);
    }
}
```

You don't "have" to use a `SortedMap` for this, you can use any kind of `Map`, but this will allow you to sort the groups by their `Date` key...don't know if it's important or not...

If you wanted to, you could go further and group the files first by year and then have a second group for the months...

```
Map<Date, Map<Date, List<File>> mapFiles = ...
```

You could use `String` as the key, but if you wanted to control the sort order, then `Date` or `Integer` would be better

Comment: Thank you It's working now, but how to give the name automatically

Comment: What do you mean?  What file name?  If you mean the zip file, why not just use `File zipFile = new File(sdf.fomat(date) + ".zip");`??